# Is it appropriate to define a non-trivial Scala case class?

Tags: scala

I'm defining a Scala class today, and I think "I need an `equals` method and a `hashCode` method; and a `copy` method would be handy too. I'll turn this into a case class." My class already has a bunch of other code, and is in no way trivial.

So fine, it all works and everything, but when the text books deal with case classes, all of the examples define them for use as value classes or 'data transfer objects'. Is it appropriate to define a non-trivial case class? Is the thought process described above OK, or do I need to think of case classes differently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `case class` provides, `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods based on the main constructor parameters, all of which are turned into `val` too. In addition, the object companion gets an `apply` and an `unapply` methods, again based on the main constructor parameters.

Also, a `case class` inherits from `Serializable` and from `Product`, and should not be extended by other classes.

If all of these things are appropriate for your class, then feel free to declare it as a `case class'.

Comment: Can you elaborate why case classes should not be extended?

Comment: @ Daniel: Never mind. I found the answer at http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Do-you-use-case-class-inheritance-td2001640.html

Answer (score 6):

Feel free, *provided it doesn't have descendants*. Extending case classes is a bad idea.

Comment: And is deprecated. scala> case class Bar(override val x: String) extends Foo("Some string")
<console>:7: warning: case class `class Bar' has case class ancestor `class Foo'.  This has been deprecated for unduly complicating both usage and implementation.  You should instead use extractors for pattern matching on non-leaf nodes.
       case class Bar(override val x: String) extends Foo("Some string")