# Adding the same object to List in Java

Tags: java

Why when I add the same object to the list:

```
Integer a = new Integer(0);
testList.add(a);
a += 1;
testList.add(a);
```

The first didin't change?

Comment: In the future, include all your relevant code when asking questions such as this.  As shown, this is not even close to being valid Java.  Also, read up on "Immutable" types (such as Integer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Integer` wrapper class is immutable in java. Not only `Integer`, all wrapper classes and `String` is immutable.

`a` is a reference which points to an object. When you run `a += 1`, that reassigns `a` to reference a new Integer object, with a different value.

You never modified the original object.

Comment: What about class that I create ? Should change?

Comment: @Nominalista immutable means every change done to the Object, `Integer` in this case, return a new Object

Comment: But what if I create MyClass?

Comment: @Nominalista you can create `MyClass`, and sure, it can be mutable if you want, but you can't overload the `+=` operator for it.

Comment: @Nominalista You *can* create a new wrapper class for `int` that allows updates, but you will lose the auto-boxing/unboxing features that are required for the `+` operator to work.

Comment: So new class is mutable or immutable for default?

Comment: class is `mutable` by default. It you make the class as `final` (having `final` properties) it will be `immutable`.

Comment: The new class is mutable if you have a method that updates its internal state.

Comment: @Nominalista [check this for immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194139/make-immutable-java-object)

Answer (score 6):

Because an `Integer` is immutable. When you modify the value of the one referenced by `a`, you're creating a new object and updating the reference to it. `testList` holds a reference to both objects.