# Java Create Wrapper Class Immutable with Mutable members

Tags: java, immutability

currently I have a class called `MatrixValue` that I want to make into an immutable object so that all my methods that interact with an instance of `MatrixValue` can't change its inner matrix. However, the problem is one of the member variables is a mutable object called `RealMatrix` that stores all the actual data of the matrix. I've already put in defensive copying into the constructor and gotten rid of any mutator methods. Here is what my class looks like so far:

```
public final class MatrixValue extends ExpressionValue{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4231050452116360135L;
    private final RealMatrix matrix;

    public MatrixValue(RealMatrix matrix){
        this.matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(matrix.getData());
    }

    public MatrixValue(double[][] values){
        matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(values);
    }

    public RealMatrix getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return matrix.getRowDimension() + "," + matrix.getColumnDimension();
    }
}
```

The problem right now is that if someone calls `matrixValue.getMatrix().setEntry(row, col, value);` they are effectively able to change the value of the final `RealMatrix` member variable. However, I still want to be able to return information regarding the `RealMatrix`. What's the best approach to fixing this hole in the class's immutability?

**EDIT**: Also do keep in mind that some matrices can become memory intensive so if possible I would prefer a solution that minimizes duplicating unnecessary information if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make immutable Java object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194139/make-immutable-java-object)

Comment: You should make a clone of the matrix in the getMatrix() method.

Comment: Thanks Michael I think that's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do probably is to return a defensive copy of `matrix` from the `getMatrix()` method. You may clone it every time and return in the method or make a copy in the constructor and only return the same copy in the method.

However, I would think what the intention of `MatrixValue` is. If it is an immutable representation of `RealMatrix`, I would consider to compose an interface for `RealMatrix` and `MatrixValue` as follows:

```
interface Matrix {
  // getters for Matrix
}
```

`RealMatrix` and `MatrixValue` will implement the interface as follows:

```
public class RealMatrix implements Matrix {
    // getters for Matrix
    // setters for RealMatrix
}

public class MatrixValue extends ExpressionValue implements Martix {
    public MatrixValue(RealMatrix matrix){
        this.matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(matrix.getData());
    }

    // getters for Matrix
}
```

This provide the intention that `RealMatrix` and `MatrixValue` are mutable and immtable representation of `Matrix` correspondingly and allow API callers to get the values from `MatrixValue` but cannot modify it.

By the way, create a new instance of `Array2DRowRealMatrix` in `MatrixValue` constructor may not enough to do a defensive copying because the array of `double[][]` can be modified externally. You need to make a copy of the array using `Arrays.copyOf` or `System.arraycopy` for each dimension of the array to avoid mutation.

Comment: Hi Wilson, I have a similar problem, and I like your interface approach. However, the getter method I use is quite complicated, so it would seem to me that this approach would violate the DRY principle. Would you still recommend using it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an interface on RealMatrix. A possible interface might be called Matrix. You internals representation could then use RealMatrix and then where you provide your external API you can instead of using the return type of RealMatrix return a Matrix instead.

```
class RealMatrix implements {
// getters and setters
}

interface Matrix  {
// only getters
}
```